# Regridding nc file: Nctoolkit to_latlon error

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I apologize in advance because this question has been asked before and also because it's my first time posting here, I'm only starting with netCDF4 and the question may be simple for many of you. I want to regrid a nc file from 0.25 to 0.125 degrees. The latitudes in the nc file are 51.3 to 53.8 and the longitudes 6.69 to 11.44. I know how to do using CDO as an external program, but I would like to regrid from Python (I use Anaconda on Windows 10).

I tried using Robert Wilson's nctoolkit as follows:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
data=nc.open_data('my_data.nc')
data.to_latlon(lon=[6.69,11.44],lat=[51.3,51.8],res=[0.125,0.125])
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

> runfile('C:/Users/sand_jv/Desktop/NetCDF4/nctoolkit_test.py', wdir='C:/Users/sand_jv/Desktop/NetCDF4')

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\sand_jv\Desktop\NetCDF4\nctoolkit_test.py", line 17, in

> data.to_latlon(lon=[6.69,11.44],lat=[51.3,53.8],res=[0.25,0.25])

> File "C:\Users\sand_jv\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nctoolkit\to_lonlat.py", line 102, in to_latlon

> self.regrid(grid=grid_file, method=method)

> File "C:\Users\sand_jv\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nctoolkit\regrid.py", line 108, in regrid

> weights_nc = run_cdo(cdo_command, target=weights_nc)

> File "C:\Users\sand_jv\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nctoolkit\runthis.py", line 319, in run_cdo

> raise ValueError(f"{command} was not successful. Check output")

> ValueError: cdo -L -genbil,C:\Users\sand_jv\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpdeeh8vl my_data.nc

> C:\Users\sand_jv\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfjklhejm.nc was not successful. Check output

I'd appreciate any help solving this problem with nctoolkit or any other alternative solutions you could provide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, as stated on the package website, this package does not work on Windows because of the need to call CDO from cygwin on Windows. CDO's python binding package (cdo on pypi) also does not work on Windows for the same reason, and based on thei reasoning there is no prospect of it working with Windows anytime soon. So I can only suggest trying Linux or xarray etc. for regridding.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as stated on the package website, this package does not work on Windows because of the need to call CDO from cygwin on Windows. CDO's python binding package (cdo on pypi) also does not work on Windows for the same reason, and based on their reasoning there is no prospect of it working with Windows anytime soon. So I can only suggest trying Linux or xarray etc. for regridding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Robert. Unfortunately my work computer has Windows. I tried with my personal computer with Linux and I had no problems, and I used xarray for regridding on Windows.